# Kendo MVC - How to interrupt remove() action for confirmation pop-up?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

i am Using Kendo MVC listview.I can catch the remove() event on view  before passing value to controller but i cannot find a way  how to interrupt or allow it to pass to controller.Here is my view:

Edit: After a bit searching , i see that i need to get data on jquery  that "e" contains.But still i cannot figure out how to do it.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ListView<AIS.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvAllService.NewsItem>()
.Name("listView")
.Events(e=>e.Remove("deleteAnnouncement"))
.TagName("div")
.ClientTemplateId("template")
.AutoBind(true)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Model(model => model.Id("ID"))
.PageSize(5)

.Read(read => read.Action("AnnouncementsRead", "Administrator"))
.Destroy(delete=>delete.Action("AnnouncementDelete","Administrator")) )
.Editable()
.Pageable()
 )
```

js:

```
  function deleteAnnouncement() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            height: 180,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {

                "Yes": function () {
                    .... 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the event at the beginning of the function then if pressed "Yes", you can manually sent Id to delete function with ajax, then refresh the page or datasource.

1) 'data: { ID: id},' You must find id of selected item to send parameter with ajax

2)  you must add parameter to your controller function.

3) Refresh page or datasource

```
 function deleteAnnouncement(event) {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    $("#dialog-confirm").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        height: 180,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            "Yes": function () {
                 $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("AnnouncementDelete","Administrator")',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: { ID: id},  // send Id of selected item 
                 success: function (result) {
                     if (result.Success) {
                         alert("basarili") // you don't have to return something                            
                     }
                     else {
                         alert("Fail");
                     }
                 },
                 async: false
             })
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it just stops the  event.I would like to do check which button is pressed.If it is pressed "Yes",data will be passed to controller otherwise event will be interrupted

Comment: will event be stopped,if yes button pressed?

Comment: I've edited my answer, If I misunderstand you, tell me with more detail what you want to do please

Comment: what i  would like to do is , to stop event if it is pressed "Cancel" button.But now it  just stops event without any check.I quess i cannot do it with jquery dialog.

Comment: Did you mean pop up which asked 'are you sure to delete record' when we pressed delete?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly that you said.I tried your revised code,now it is just passing to controller without checking which button is pressed.It should be paused until "Yes" or "Cancel" button pressed then it will be disturbed(If Cancel button is pressed) or it will be passed to controller

Comment: Try, after modifying my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have done it myself.Write almost same with 
your s.I needed to retrieve value that will be send and after success reload the datasource of ListView and i changed dataType o "text" because when i use "json" i got error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code that retrieves selected data from Listview , if pressed "Yes" button ,pass values to controller after the delete event finishes,it refreshes datasource of Listview manually:

**Js**:

```
function refreshdataSource() {
 $("#listView").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
 }

function deleteAnnouncement(e) {
e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
$("#dialog-confirm").css("visibility", "visible");
var data = e.model["ID"];
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
height: 180,
width: 400,
modal: true,
buttons: {

Okay: function () {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '@Url.Action("AnnouncementDelete", "Administrator")',
data: {
ID: data
},
dataType: "text",
success: function () { refreshdataSource(); },
error: function () { alert("Error occured!!!") }
});

$(this).dialog("close");

},
Cancel: function () {

$(this).dialog("close");
}}});
 };
```

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<AIS.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvAllService.NewsItem>()
.Name("listView")
.Events(e=>e.Remove("deleteAnnouncement"))
.TagName("div")
.ClientTemplateId("template")
.AutoBind(true)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Model(model => model.Id("ID"))
.PageSize(5)

.Read(read => read.Action("AnnouncementsRead", "Administrator"))
.Destroy(delete=>delete.Action("AnnouncementDelete","Administrator")) )
.Editable()
.Pageable()
)
```